# Why won't a function within a "namespace" JavaScript file populate a dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-namespaces

I have 2 external JavaScript files, one is set up like a "namespace", and the other file calls it.

Here is how my "namespace" looks like

```
var GlobalScript = {
    GetAllStates: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: URLParam.GetStatesForDropdown,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                ShowStates(data);
            }
        })

    },
    ShowStates: function (stateData) {
        $("#acVendorState").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: stateData,
            dataTextField: "StateName",
            dataValueField: "StateID",
            animation: false,
            optionLabel: {
                StateName: "-- Select State --"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the script that is calling the GetAllStates() function,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GlobalScript.GetAllStates();
});
```

Now this doesn't work, however, if make the "namespace" file look like this...

```
function ShowStates(stateData){
$("#acVendorState").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: stateData,
        dataTextField: "StateName",
        dataValueField: "StateID",
        animation: false,
        optionLabel: {
            StateName: "-- Select State --"
        }
    });
}

var GlobalScript = {
        GetAllStates: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: URLParam.GetStatesForDropdown,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    ShowStates(data);
                }
            })      
        }
    }
```

Then my view that has the dropdownlist will populate.

My question is how to make it work the way I have it the first way because if I do it the second way then its kind of pointless (at least to the best of my knowledge) to do it the way I am doing it.

Comment: In your first example, have you placed a debugger in the success callback and made sure that the call to `ShowStates()` is actually working?

Comment: @p.s.w.g, that was a typo

Comment: In JavaScript, it is traditional for constructor functions, and *only* constructor functions to be named starting with a capital letter.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` — You are making a GET request, it makes zero sense to get a Content-Type request header for it. There is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: @Quentin, i just noticed your comments now...I'm not necessarily a JavaScript or JQuery developer. I am not an expert with it and not necessarily a newbie with it. Up until last year I been involved with server side development. So I am learning new things every day with client side development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowStates` isn't a variable. It is a property of the object assigned to `GlobalScript`.

`ShowStates(data);` should be `GlobalScript.ShowStates(data);`

Comment: That worked...So just so I am understanding to call a function from within the GlobalScript, I need to always use the namespace and the function?

Comment: Or some other reference to it.

Comment: @Chris alternatively you could save the `this` reference in a variable outside the `$.ajax()` call, and use that to reference the other function. Using the variable name `GlobalScript` is a little fragile.

Comment: @Pointy, could you elaborate on GlobalScript being a little fragile as opposed to using the this reference?

Comment: @Chris well in practical terms it's not a big deal, but if `GlobalScript` were to take on a new value for some reason (like maybe a bug), then the function could stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your js

```
var GlobalScript = {
    GetAllStates: function () {
        var self = this; // <= self object created
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: URLParam.GetStatesForDropdown,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                self.ShowStates(data);
            }
        })

    },
    ShowStates: function (stateData) {
        $("#acVendorState").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: stateData,
            dataTextField: "StateName",
            dataValueField: "StateID",
            animation: false,
            optionLabel: {
                StateName: "-- Select State --"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Quentin answered first, I did mark your answer as useful because it does work too.